# Questions about coronavirus & film/tv production?

Tags: discussion, scope

Looking at the [help for what's On Topic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), the following is on topic:

> Questions about a movie or TV show's production
> Questions relating to the film and TV industry

but this is off topic:

> TV news, sports and current affairs

I was wanting to ask a question (I don't have the phrasing down yet), essentially asking that since coronavirus shut down most TV/movie production, is there a "bottleneck" coming where new content will be rare, until companies can restart production/filming?

It is related to production (on topic), but related to current events (off topic).  Is such a question welcome here?

Comment: Such a bottleneck would be arbitrary and not the same for all companies. Considering that there are a great number of companies, it is an unanswerable question. There have already been shows where they couldn't finish the season earlier this year, yet IIRC a Netflix boss claims they've got plenty of shows ready for release over the next couple of months.

Comment: Related? https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4705/please-re-open-this-question-that-was-closed-as-opinion-based-or-unclear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My interpretation of

> TV news, sports and current affairs

being off topic, is that this means "TV news shows, sports shows and current affair shows" are off topic.

I don't think that a question about the impact of the pandemic on the production and distribution of TV and Movies are off topic.

As with all Meta answers please upvote/downvote to agree/disagree.

Comment: Whilst I agree that the question in it's raw form is probably on topic it seems to be asking something that is self-evident. It's a known fact that most shows have halted production until the pandemic eases so there is a dearth of fresh (dramatic) TV right now. So I'm not sure what value the question actually has. 2c

Comment: I agree @Paulie_D .. but I guess that is a different point, to be answered with voting.